# Issue with Uicollectionview for nib but didn't get a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am new for IOS development , and I try to use `UIcollectionView` to show the photo.

I create a `xib file` from New file -> `iOS` -> `User Interface` -> `View` , and add a `Collection View` like the following picture.

[image]

But I got the following error log when it crash.

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
    reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] 
    loaded the "AITLocalGridViewController" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

And it seems didn't call `viewDidLoad`

I have search for some information , some information indicated that I **dint not connect the collection view in xib file**

But I don't understand what it mean.

Could some one help me and teach me what to do ?

Comment: You should set files' owner to the ViewContolller class that you want to use. and then connect View to the file's owner

Comment: @SunnyShah I have set files' owner to View , but it is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have connected `UIcollectionview` `IBOutlet` with “`collectionview` “ that you declared in your program. And also you should make delegate&data source connection(For making this, click on th `Uicollectionview` in the xib. Select Connection Inspector. Where you can see `delegate` and `datasource`.By pressing ctrl button drag and connect it to File’s Owner.)

Comment: I click on the `Uicollectionview`. Pressing ctrl button and connect it to `File’s Owner`. And choose the `delegate` and `datasource`. I also connect `collectionview` to `header file` for create `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;`. But it is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the view in Storyboard and use the UICollectionView as direct child.

Comment: It helps in some cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure UICollectionViewController's "view" outlet is set to a UICollectionView. Setting the "collectionView" to a UICollectionView is not enough for a UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious, also make sure that the `UICollectionView` is inside a `UICollectionViewController`. This can be overlooked when you do something like adding an embedded view into your project, where the default embedded view is the standard view controller.

[image: http://g.recordit.co/cZFwsYWhmp.gif]

Comment: But what if you want to use a UICollectionView inside of a UIView? I need to place things around my CollectionView and I can't do this with a CollectionViewController that only allows a CollectionView in it but nothing else.

Comment: @David not so obvious, especially considering that with an UIViewController for some reason sometimes it worked.. At least your solution is the one that worked on my case.